# How to create a CRC function in PHP?

Tags: php, crc

How to create a CRC(cyclic redundancy checksum) program in php. There are lot of resources on internet for java and c++ CRC functions but there no implemention in PHP for CRC. Please help

Answer (score 3):

This function already exists in PHP: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crc32.php

Comment: how to check it on receiver end ?
how to decrypt it ?
i need end to end crc function!

Comment: CRC isn't an encryption function it's a hash function.

Comment: i am a newbie i php but i want to know that after putting string in crc32 function it gave me a number then how to 
varify it that there is error in that string or not?

Comment: How I said, `crc32()` is a hash function there is only one thing what you need to be aware of and this is written in the documentation (warning section): https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crc32.php. 

If the generated hassum doesn't match the hashsum you compare with, then depends most likely on this.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the next Helper_CRC.php class, which you can use like:

Helper_CRC::getCRC();

```
 <?php
   class Helper_CRC
   {
       static function getCRC($object):int {
           try{
               $stringify = json_encode($object) ?? "";
               return crc32($stringify);
           }
           catch (Exception $e){
               return 0;
           }
       }
   }
```

Comment: Encoding equal objects can result in a different JSON and CRC because of the key order.